# How can I write a function to extract only zpcum5 from .stdmetrics_z in lidR?

Tags: lidr

I've determined that zpcum5 (available through .stdmetrics_z in lidR) is one of the metrics valuable to model my forest inventory.

I tried to modify the source code, but the internal function `fast_table()` prevented it from working in my own function.

Could someone explain what the fast_table does to d? Or to suggest another way to get zpcum5.

```
z <- 7
zmin <- 2
zmax <- 12

# code to get zpcum5
(breaks <- seq(zmin, zmax, (zmax-zmin)/10))
(d <- findInterval(z[z>zmin], breaks))
(d <- fast_table(d, 10))
(d <- d / sum(d)*100)
(d <- cumsum(d)[5]) # 1:9
(d <- as.list(d))

(names(d) <- paste0("zpcum", 5))
```

Comment: for context, I'm trying to reduce the size of individual raster tiles. When trying to merge the tiles with terra::merge(), it bailed due to raster size being too large.

Comment: the function `tabulate` can replace `fast_table`